# Postgres window function and group by exception

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm trying to put together a query that will retrieve the statistics of a user (profit/loss) as a cumulative result, over a period of time.

Here's the query I have so far:

```
SELECT p.name, e.date, 
    sum(sp.payout) OVER (ORDER BY e.date)
    - sum(s.buyin) OVER (ORDER BY e.date) AS "Profit/Loss" 
FROM result r 
    JOIN game g ON r.game_id = g.game_id 
    JOIN event e ON g.event_id = e.event_id 
    JOIN structure s ON g.structure_id = s.structure_id 
    JOIN structure_payout sp ON g.structure_id = sp.structure_id
                            AND r.position = sp.position 
    JOIN player p ON r.player_id = p.player_id 
WHERE p.player_id = 17 
GROUP BY p.name, e.date, e.event_id, sp.payout, s.buyin
ORDER BY p.name, e.date ASC
```

The query will run. However, the result is slightly incorrect. The reason is that an `event` can have multiple games (with different `sp.payouts`). Therefore, the above comes out with multiple rows if a user has 2 results in an event with different payouts (i.e. there are 4 games per event, and a user gets £20 from one, and £40 from another).

The obvious solution would be to amend the `GROUP BY` to:

```
GROUP BY p.name, e.date, e.event_id
```

However, Postgres complains at this as it doesn't appear to be recognizing that `sp.payout` and `s.buyin` are inside an aggregate function. I get the error:

> column "sp.payout" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function

I'm running 9.1 on Ubuntu Linux server.
Am I missing something, or could this be a genuine defect in Postgres?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are **not**, in fact, using aggregate functions. You are using **[window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)**. That's why PostgreSQL demands `sp.payout` and `s.buyin` to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

By appending an `OVER` clause, the aggregate function `sum()` is turned into a window function, which aggregates values per partition while *keeping* all rows.

You can **combine window functions and aggregate functions**. Aggregations are applied first. I did not understand from your description how you want to handle multiple payouts / buyins per event. As a guess, I calculate a sum of them per event. *Now* I can remove `sp.payout` and `s.buyin` from the `GROUP BY` clause and get one row per `player` and `event`:

```sql
SELECT p.name
     , e.event_id
     , e.date
     , sum(sum(sp.payout)) OVER w
     - sum(sum(s.buyin  )) OVER w AS "Profit/Loss" 
FROM   player            p
JOIN   result            r ON r.player_id     = p.player_id  
JOIN   game              g ON g.game_id       = r.game_id 
JOIN   event             e ON e.event_id      = g.event_id 
JOIN   structure         s ON s.structure_id  = g.structure_id 
JOIN   structure_payout sp ON sp.structure_id = g.structure_id
                          AND sp.position     = r.position
WHERE  p.player_id = 17 
GROUP  BY e.event_id
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY e.date, e.event_id)
ORDER  BY e.date, e.event_id;
```

In this expression: `sum(sum(sp.payout)) OVER w`, the outer `sum()` is a window function, the inner `sum()` is an aggregate function.

Assuming `p.player_id` and `e.event_id` are `PRIMARY KEY` in their respective tables.

I added `e.event_id` to the `ORDER BY` of the `WINDOW` clause to arrive at a deterministic sort order. (There could be multiple events on the same date.) Also included `event_id` in the result to distinguish multiple events per day.

While the query restricts to a *single* player (`WHERE  p.player_id = 17`), we don't need to add `p.name` or `p.player_id` to `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. If one of the joins would multiply rows unduly, the resulting sum would be incorrect (partly or completely multiplied). Grouping by `p.name` could not repair the query then.

I also removed `e.date` from the `GROUP BY` clause. The primary key `e.event_id` covers all columns of the input row [since PostgreSQL 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-9-1.html#AEN107211).

***If*** you change the query to return multiple players at once, adapt:

```sql
...
WHERE  p.player_id < 17  -- example - multiple players
GROUP  BY p.name, p.player_id, e.date, e.event_id  -- e.date and p.name redundant
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY p.name, p.player_id, e.date, e.event_id)
ORDER  BY p.name, p.player_id, e.date, e.event_id;
```

Unless `p.name` is defined unique (?), group and order by `player_id` additionally to get correct results in a deterministic sort order.

I only kept `e.date` and `p.name` in `GROUP BY` to have identical sort order in all clauses, hoping for a performance benefit. Else, you can remove the columns there. (Similar for just `e.date` in the first query.)

Comment: The first query is working, however, the output of the query isn't giving the required results.  I can see what amendment would work in theory, but Postgres doesn't like it.  I'll try the above later and let you know.  however, it looks like there will be 2 rows in the output of your query if an "event_id" has more than one "payout" amount.

Comment: I just tried it with the amendments you've suggested, and it does come back with multiple rows where there are multiple sp.payout values for a single event_id.

Comment: @Martin: See my amended answer.

Comment: wouldn't you need to `partition by p.name, e.event_id` in your window function as well for the grouping to work as expected?

Comment: @RyanTuck: There were several unexplained / fuzzy bits. I improved and clarified (or at least hope so).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , may I just say !   I LOVE the formatting of your first sql snippet in this answer.  Utilizing both of the 2 dimensions available to the human visual system for organizing code REALLY makes it digestible, and MORE coders should do this to achieve higher code density simultaneously with faster visual parsing