# Group and count events per time intervals, plus running total

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm a fairly new Postgres user, I'm sure there's an answer to this already but I can't find it.
I need to analyze some data in an activity log table, grouping the the results by time period.

A simple version of the problem would be a table with three fields:

```
    Column    |           Type           |              Modifiers
--------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------
 period_start | timestamp with time zone | not null
 user_id      | text                     | not null
 action       | text                     | not null
```

The action string I want to capture could be 'create_entry' (yes, I know that sucks as good db design but I'm stuck with it)

The output I'm looking for is a report showing count of 'create_entry' actions by year and month. Something like:

```
 Year | Month | Entries
------+-------+----------
 2013 |  12   | 14345
 2014 |   1   | 9876
 2014 |   2   | 10234
```

My instinct is to attack this with sub-queries but looking around there seems to be a suggestion that loops might be the way to go.

Either way, I'm out of my depth and looking for a push in the right direction.

**EDIT**

A supplementary question based on a request that came in while I was typing this.. A variation on the above that would show a cumulative total month by month (although I'd like to think I could figure that out by myself based on the approach to the above - I'm just adding this in case it's relevant to the approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to `GROUP BY` the years and months in your table, for every row that has an `action` of `create_entry`:

```
SELECT
  DATE_PART('YEAR', period_start) as Year,
  DATE_PART('MONTH', period_start) as Month,
  COUNT(*) as Entries
FROM activity_log
WHERE action = 'create_entry'
GROUP BY Year, Month;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5433/1)

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow - DATE_PART and date_trunc - I'd never seen them before

Comment: Not sure if there's any difference between them.  @Erwin would know, he's much more of an expert than I.

Comment: Oh.  `DATE_PART` returns a number (2013, 2, etc) and `DATE_TRUNC` returns a time stamp, truncated to that part.  So, my way would look more like your example output.

Comment: Sometimes I hate having to choose a preferred answer... Both excellent, both +1'd. I'm not qualified to say which is the 'best', I suspect it's probably @Erwin's But I'm choosing this one because it's the solution that I've actually used.

Comment: @PerryW: I proposed `date_trunc()`, straying from your proposed result format, because aggregating on a single column is cheaper than on two columns. The most interesting bit is the running count, though, and that it only needs a single query level for that.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to truncate timestamps to the month and cover both year and month in a single column. You can use `to_char()` to format that any way you like.

To get the running count you mention in your supplementary question, add a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```sql
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', period_start), 'Mon YYYY') AS month
     , count(*) AS month_ct
     , sum(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('month', period_start)) AS running_ct
FROM   activity_log
WHERE  action = 'create_entry'
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', period_start);
```

Window functions are executed *after* aggregate functions, so we can run a window function over an aggregate in the same query level. See:

- [Postgres window function and group by exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844903/postgres-window-function-and-group-by-exception/8845062#8845062)

It's essential to use the same basic expression in the window function and in `GROUP BY`: `date_trunc('month', period_start)`.

Since you operate on `timestamptz`, fix possible corner case issues with your time zone by truncating to the time boundary **in your time zone**. Using `'Europe/Vienna'` in my example:

```sql
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', period_start AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna'), 'Mon YYYY') AS month
     , COUNT(*) AS month_ct
     , sum(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('month', period_start AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna')) AS running_ct
FROM   activity_log
WHERE  action = 'create_entry'
GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', period_start AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna');
```

Since Postgres 12 we could also feed the time zone as 3rd parameter to `date_trunc()`, but that would return `timestamptz`, which would result in the next corner case issue with `to_char()`. You'll want to display *local* time units, so `AT TIME ZONE` is better.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eaRJ6Mgr)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7d2a0/1)</sub>