# Postgres GROUP BY, then sort

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate

I have a database query like:

```
SELECT 
  Foo,
  Foo2,
  some_calc as Bar,
  some_other_calc as Bar2,
From
 FooBar
-- some inner joins for the calcs
GROUP BY FOO
ORDER BY Bar DESC, Bar2 DESC;
```

I want to order by database with the order query, and then group together `FOO`s so that that first grouped block contains the `FOO` with the greatest Bar. The second grouped block of `FOO`s contains the seconds highest Bar, etc.

But this doesn't work as Postgres doesn't allow random grouping:

`column "Bar" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

How can I fix this?

Sample data and output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════╦════╦
║ FO  ║ Bar      ║  Bar 2  ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════════╬
║  6  ║     10   ║         ║
║  4  ║     110  ║         ║
║  3  ║     120  ║         ║
║  8  ║     140  ║         ║
║  3  ║     180  ║         ║
║  3  ║     190  ║         ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════╩════╩
```

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════╦════╦
║ FO  ║ Bar      ║  Bar 2  ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════════╬
║  3  ║     190  ║         ║
║  3  ║     180  ║         ║
║  3  ║     120  ║         ║
║  8  ║     140  ║         ║
║  4  ║     110  ║         ║
║  6  ║     10   ║         ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════╩════╩
```

Comment: [Ain't no such thing as "Postgre".](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Comment: How to sort two groups of `foo` with equally high `bar`? Smallest `foo` first or last? Can there be NULL values? Your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
SELECT foo, <some calc> AS bar, bar2
FROM   foobar
ORDER  BY max(<some calc>) OVER (PARTITION BY foo) DESC NULLS LAST  -- can't refer to bar
        , bar DESC NULLS LAST  -- but you can here
        , foo DESC NULLS LAST;
```

`bar` does not have to be a column, can be any valid expression, even an aggregate function (in combination with `GROUP BY`) - just not another window function, which can't be nested. Example:

- [PostgreSQL - Referencing another aggregate column in a window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085609/postgresql-referencing-another-aggregate-column-in-a-window-function/23089169#23089169)

You **cannot**, however, refer to a column alias (output column name) on the same query level within a window function. You have to spell out the expression again, or move the calculation to a subquery or CTE.
You *can* refer to output column names in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` otherwise (but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause). Explanation:

- [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)
- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119489/postgresql-where-count-condition/8119815#8119815)

Since it has not been defined we must expect NULL values. Typically you want NULL values last, so add `NULLS LAST` in descending order. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Assuming you want bigger `foo` first in case of ties with `bar`.

Comment: I still get `column bar does not exist`

Comment: If `bar` refers to an expression, you have to spell out the expression in the window function and cannot refer to a column alias of the same expression in the `SELECT` list. You can refer to the output column name (alias) in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` otherwise (but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause) . Detailed explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8119815/939860) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19849537/939860).

Comment: Thanks, yes bar is an expression on two columns

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter could you please give me some insights on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818667/improve-postgressql-aggregation-query-performance

Answer (score 4):

You just want `order by`.  `Group by` reduces (in general) the number of rows by aggregation.

You can accomplish this using window functions:

```
SELECT Foo, Bar, Bar2,
From FooBar
ORDER BY MAX(Bar) OVER (PARTITION BY Foo) DESC,
         Foo;
```

Comment: Bar is really `some_calc` as bar via an inner join. This only works with columns i think

Comment: I think this is close.  May need to sort by window desc, ***bar desc,*** foo...   I say this because the window bar will always be max value for each foo, and thus you also need the sort by bar. and as to @daynaJuliana if there's inner calculations you could set it all up as a CTE or subselect.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this do what you're asking for?

If not, it would help if you could give some sample data in the query and show how you'd want it as the output.

```
SELECT 
  Foo,
  MAX(some_calc) as Bar,
  MAX(some_other_calc) as Bar2,
From
 FooBar
##some inner joins for the calcs
GROUP BY FOO;
```

Comment: Could you give sample data and expected sorted output? I think more than one people are unable to comprehend as to what do you want to do here.

Comment: Added a sample output