# Window function with same result in subgroup

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Based on this table:

| file | path | created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 08/22/A | 2022-08-22 22:00:00 |
| AAA | 08/22/A | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 |
| AAA | 08/21/A | 2022-08-21 20:00:00 |
| AAA | 08/20/A | 2022-08-20 21:00:00 |
| BBB | 08/22/B | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 |
| CCC | 08/22/C | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 |
| CCC | 08/21/C | 2022-08-21 21:00:00 |

I have the following query in PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH ranked_messages AS (
    select file, created, path,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY file ORDER BY created DESC)  AS rating_in_section
    from files
    order by file
)
SELECT path FROM ranked_messages WHERE rating_in_section > 1 group by path order by path desc;
```

But results are not what I want:

| path |
| --- |
| 08/22/A |
| 08/21/C |
| 08/21/A |
| 08/20/A |

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3bc6a/1

I really want this:

| path |
| --- |
| 08/21/C |
| 08/21/A |
| 08/20/A |

The window function marks data without group by `path`. The intermediary state is:

| file | path | created | raiting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 08/22/A | 2022-08-22 22:00:00 | 1 |
| AAA | 08/22/A | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 | 2 |
| AAA | 08/21/A | 2022-08-21 20:00:00 | 3 |
| AAA | 08/20/A | 2022-08-20 21:00:00 | 4 |
| BBB | 08/22/B | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 | 1 |
| CCC | 08/22/C | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 | 1 |
| CCC | 08/21/C | 2022-08-21 21:00:00 | 2 |

But I need:

| file | path | created | raiting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 08/22/A | 2022-08-22 22:00:00 | 1 |
| AAA | 08/22/A | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 | 1 |
| AAA | 08/21/A | 2022-08-21 20:00:00 | 2 |
| AAA | 08/20/A | 2022-08-20 21:00:00 | 3 |
| BBB | 08/22/B | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 | 1 |
| CCC | 08/22/C | 2022-08-22 21:00:00 | 1 |
| CCC | 08/21/C | 2022-08-21 21:00:00 | 2 |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you really using Postgres 9.3 as implied by the fiddle? Please always declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw in `GROUP  BY file, path`:

```sql
WITH ranked_messages AS (
   SELECT path
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY file ORDER BY max(created) DESC) AS rating_in_section
   FROM   files
   GROUP  BY file, path
   )
SELECT path
FROM   ranked_messages
WHERE  rating_in_section > 1
GROUP  BY path
ORDER  BY path DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=df2cd93b6949fbbce36065e480b84455)*

Assuming you want to work with `max(created)`, i.e. the latest timestamp per group.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL - Referencing another aggregate column in a window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085609/postgresql-referencing-another-aggregate-column-in-a-window-function/23089169#23089169)
- [Postgres window function and group by exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844903/postgres-window-function-and-group-by-exception/8845062#8845062)