# group by rows into multiple groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table

```
id    index   value
1       1        2
2       1        3 
3       2        6
4       3        8
```

I can do like this:

```
select sum(value) from table group by index
```

But what I want is that each row can go to multiple groups, pseudocode

```
 select sum(value) from table group by >= index
```

Basically the indexes are 1,2,3 and I want it to group these into 3 seperate groups.

1. Sum of values where index is bigger/equal than 1
2. Sum of values where index is bigger/equal than 2
3. Sum of values where index is bigger/equal than 3

This must be a generic function, so I actually would not know the index level, as it is hardcoded here.

This is example output:

```
indexLevelBiggerEquals   sumValue
          1                 19          -- sum of all rows that are >= 1
          2                 14          -- sum of all rows that are >= 2
          3                 8           -- sum of all rows that are >= 3
```

Comment: sum(case when index >= 1 then value else 0 end) ...

Comment: Can you add an example on how the actual output should look like? Do you want all that in different columns?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added example output

Comment: Then Marth's answer is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One sum for each "index >" group, use case to chose values to sum:

```
select sum(case when index >= 1 then value else 0 end) sum1,
       sum(case when index >= 2 then value else 0 end) sum2,
       sum(case when index >= 3 then value else 0 end) sum3
from table group by index
```

This is probably what you want:

```
select index,
       (select sum(value) from table where index >= t1.index)
from (select distinct index from table) t1;
```

Comment: This must be a generic function, so I actually would not know the index levels. Index could be 1,5,50,500

Comment: How do you "enter" the index?

Comment: Index is the column in database, as you see, in the current data, index values are 1,2,3. It should group by index, but not equals, but >=.

Comment: Right, you need a join. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function, working over a limited selection of the table (note that the selection defaults to `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` upto `CURRENT ROW`, which is what you want here, but you could specify something else) :

```
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES
(1,       1,        2),
(2,       1,        3),
(3,       2,        6),
(4,       3,        8)
;
```

---

```
SELECT index, SUM(value) OVER ( ORDER BY index DESC )
FROM tmp;


┌───────┬─────┐
│ index │ sum │
├───────┼─────┤
│     3 │   8 │
│     2 │  14 │
│     1 │  19 │
│     1 │  19 │
└───────┴─────┘
(4 rows)
```

---

**EDIT :**

Using other functions in the query :

```
SELECT index,
       COUNT(index),
       SUM(SUM(value)) OVER ( ORDER BY index DESC )                                                                             
FROM tmp 
GROUP BY index;
┌───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ index │ count │ sum │
├───────┼───────┼─────┤
│     3 │     1 │   8 │
│     2 │     1 │  14 │
│     1 │     2 │  19 │
└───────┴───────┴─────┘
(3 rows)
```

The `SUM(SUM(value))` is needed because `value` must appear in a aggregate function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844903/postgres-window-function-and-group-by-exception) for a better explanation.

Comment: You need another `order by index desc` for the actual query to make sure you get that result - but apart from that, I think that is a nifty trick!

Comment: Why there is 2 rows with index 1?

Comment: @Jaanus : Use `SELECT DISTINCT ON (index)` if you don't want multiple rows with the same index. As for why, window functions  do not group rows together in the final result (unlike `GROUP BY`).

Comment: How can I use other functions like `count()`, I would like to count the grows in each group? I tried to use `count(index)`, but it sayd that `index  must appear in the GROUP BY clause`.

Comment: @Jaanus : Edited my answer. Unsure what you mean by 'grows', but I added an example on how to use the `COUNT()` function.