# Rounding of the numeric values

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, rounding

I want to round of the values of two columns:

```
select a.region as "Regions",
       a.suminsured,2 as "SumInsured" ,
       a.suminsured/b.sum*100 as pct 
from (
    SELECT  region, sum(suminsured) as suminsured 
    FROM "Exposure_commune" group by region
) a,
(select sum(suminsured) FROM "Exposure_commune") b
```

I want the `suminsured` and `pct` columns to come with 2 decimal places. Can someone tell me what I should do?

Comment: Use the function round, eg.: round(a.suminsured,2) as "SumInsured"

Comment: Data types are essential. Is `suminsured` defined `numeric`? The table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) would clarify everything

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly numeric with two parameters. Second parameter for round decimal.

```
select sum(column_name::numeric(10,2)) from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`round()`** with two parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE), which only works for the data type [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html).

While being at it, your query can be simpler and faster:

```
SELECT region
     , round(sum(suminsured), 2) AS suminsured
     , round((sum(suminsured) * 100) / sum(sum(suminsured)) OVER (), 2) AS pct 
FROM  "Exposure_commune"
GROUP  BY 1;
```

You can use sum() as window function to get the total without additional subquery, which is cheaper. Related:

- [Postgres window function and group by exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844903/postgres-window-function-and-group-by-exception/8845062#8845062)

Multiplying first is typically cheaper and more exact (although that barely matters with `numeric`).

#### Data type is not `numeric`

For data types double precision of real
You can ...

- just cast to `numeric` to use the same function.
- multiply by 100, cast to `integer` and divide by `100.0`.
- multiply by 100 and use the simple `round()` and devide by `100`.

The simple `round()` with just one parameter works for floating point types as well.

Demonstrating all three variants:

```
SELECT region
     , round(sum(suminsured), 2) AS suminsured
     , (sum(suminsured) * 100)::int / 100.0 AS suminsured2
     , round(sum(suminsured) * 100) / 100 AS suminsured3
     , round((sum(suminsured) * 100) / sum(sum(suminsured)) OVER (), 2) AS pct 
     , ((sum(suminsured) * 10000) / sum(sum(suminsured)) OVER ())::int / 100.0 AS pct2
     , round((sum(suminsured) * 10000) / sum(sum(suminsured)) OVER ()) / 100 AS pct3
FROM  "Exposure_commune"
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56acc/4)

Comment: thanx for your help but it is not working for me ..i have tried this but it throwing error    function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

Comment: @preeti: Well, start by providing your version of Postgres and the table definition *in the question*. It's certainly working in modern Postgres, I added a demo. Ah .. **double precision** ... Did you see the part where I mention **only works for the data type numeric**? And did you see my comment where I ask for the **data type**?