# Convert numeric result to percentage with decimal digits

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, aggregate-functions, percentage

I have this query:

```
Select count(incidentnumber) as average
from incidents
Where IncidentStationGround <> firstpumparriving_deployedfromstation;
```

I got a result, it's something like 20,000. But how can I convert this number to a percentage? Plus, I want the results in decimal, can I?

Comment: **Would this work??**

`Select (count(incidentnumber)*100 /(select count(incidentnumber) from incidents)) as score from incidents
Where IncidentStationGround <> firstpumparriving_deployedfromstation;`

Answer (score 3):

your query in comment should work
cast count to decimal to achieve decimal percentage

```
count(incidentnumber)::decimal*100
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot but what does : : means ?**

Comment: :: is casting operator in postgres

Answer (score 0):

Assuming percentage of the total count:

```sql
SELECT (count(incidentnumber) FILTER (WHERE IncidentStationGround <> firstpumparriving_deployedfromstation)
      * 100.0) / count(*) AS average
FROM   incidents;
```

Multiply the result with a `numeric` constant: `100.0` (with decimal point!) to implicitly cast the `bigint` result of `count()` to `numeric`. (Or cast explicitly.)

[`round()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) is optional. You get many decimal places without it.

- [No function matches the given name and argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751372/no-function-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types/24771122#24771122)

Assuming that `incidentnumber` is defined `NOT NULL`, so `count(*)` does the same as `count(incidentnumber)`, just a bit faster. (A table definition would provide that information.)

Assuming Postgres 9.4 or later.
Related answer with links and alternative for older versions:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

About `round()` and `numeric`:

- [Rounding of the numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385131/rounding-of-the-numeric-values/29386280#29386280)