# Find relative percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, percentage

I have a poll with votes from users. For example:

Do you want a Fiat?

```
id | answer
1    yes
2    no 
3    yes
...
25   no

count = 20 yes / 5 no

(20 * 100) /25 = 80% Yes
(5 * 100) /25 = 20% No
```

So, 80% want a Fiat, and 20% don't want. Obviously I can do something like:

```
select answer, count(*) as total from fast_survey group by answer;
```

However this will show the count and I am looking for the relative percentage. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: As always, actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and Postgres version would be instrumental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE answer)     * 100.0 / count(*), 2) AS pct_yes
     , round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT answer) * 100.0 / count(*), 2) AS pct_no
FROM   fast_survey;
```

```
pct_yes | pct_no
--------+-------
  80.00 |  20.00
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f1ad5257d529ee851e119edf0a347ad)*

I multiply with `100.0` (not <strike>`100`</strike>) to avoid integer division. The result is type `numeric` which can be fed to `round()` to prettify. See:

- [Calculating rates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031806/calculating-rates-in-postgresql/50033357#50033357)

Assuming `answer` is `boolean`. Else, adapt.

The aggregate `FILTER` clause has been introduced with Postgres 9.4. See:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

Should be as fast as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

You can `COUNT` over partitions to get the values for each answer type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT answer,
       COUNT(*) OVER (partition BY answer) AS total,
       COUNT(*) OVER (partition BY answer) * 100 /
       COUNT(*) OVER () AS percentage
FROM fast_survey
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/69c74/3)

If you want more precision in the percentage (for the above query it's an integer divide), cast the first `COUNT` to a `FLOAT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT answer,
       COUNT(*) OVER (partition BY answer) AS total,
       CAST(COUNT(*) OVER (partition BY answer) AS FLOAT) * 100 /
       COUNT(*) OVER () AS percentage
FROM fast_survey
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/69c74/9)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT 
    t1.answer, t1.votes / t2.total_votes
FROM
    (SELECT answer, count(*) AS votes FROM fast_survey GROUP BY answer) AS t1,
    (SELECT count(*) AS total_votes FROM fast_survey) AS t2
;
```

This will also work if your survey has multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

just join it with the table where you ciunt all records without division on answers and count percentage...Something like this

```
select answer, count(*) / max(totalCount) * 100 as total from fast_survey group by answer
left join (select count(*) FROM fast_survey as totalCount) as all on true
```