# How to extract the max of the sum of ~120k rows in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database for a bike store, with a table I called
`"SalesOrderHeader"` that has, among others, these 2 columns: `CustomerID`, `TotalDue`.

It holds information about all sales of the bike store. So if f.e. a customer bought 2 times in total from the store, there will be 2 registries of his `CustomerID` with the amount of money (`TotalDue`) he paid each time.
[image: Here is a screenshot of the table in excel, just to get the idea.]

How to write a select query that will show the 1 (or more, in case of a tie) customer that has paid the most in total. The result has to bring up 2 columns one with the `CustomerID` and one with the `TotalMoneyHePaid`.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You have a mix of quoted and unquoted identifiers in the question. Be aware that [identifiers are case sensitive in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860). Assuming all unquoted identifiers for my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery in your HAVING clause to get this:

```
SELECT customerid,
    sum(totaldue)
FROM SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY customerid
HAVING sum(totaldue) = (
        SELECT sum(totaldue)
        FROM SalesOrderHeader
        GROUP BY customerID
        ORDER BY sum(totalDue) DESC LIMIT 1
        )
```

The subquery:

```
    SELECT sum(totaldue)
    FROM SalesOrderHeader
    GROUP BY customerID
    ORDER BY sum(totalDue) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Is getting the largest customer's `sum(totalDue)` by ordering the records by that `sum(totaldue)` and then keeping only the first record `LIMIT 1`. We use that in the `HAVING` clause to compare that to the `Sum(totaldue)` for each customer. If the customer in the main query has a `sum(totaldue)` equivalent to the subquery's result, then we keep the record.

```
postgres=> CREATE TABLE salesorderheader
postgres-> (
postgres(>   customerid integer,
postgres(>   totaldue integer
postgres(> );
CREATE TABLE

postgres=> INSERT INTO salesorderheader VALUES
postgres->   (1, 10),
postgres->   (1, 12),
postgres->   (2, 22),
postgres->   (3, 5),
postgres->   (4, 4);
INSERT 0 5

postgres=> SELECT customerid, sum(totaldue) FROM SalesOrderHeader GROUP BY customerid HAVING sum(totaldue) = (SELECT sum(totaldue) FROM SalesOrderHeader GROUP BY customerID ORDER BY sum(totalDue) desc LIMIT 1);
 customerid | sum
------------+-----
          1 |  22
          2 |  22
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That edge case is from OP: "The question is to write a select query that will show the 1 (or more, in case of a tie) customer that has paid in total, the most." This query will port better to MySQL, but the Window Function version by Erwin will work fine in most every other RDBMS (Oracle, Sql Server, Teradata, etc..)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I used your solution because it is closer to my knowledge (new to PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [window function `rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) over the sum of `totaldue` in a subquery:

```
SELECT customerid, total_money_paid
FROM  (
   SELECT customerid, sum(totaldue) AS total_money_paid
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(totaldue) DESC NULLS LAST) AS rnk
   FROM   salesorderheader
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

This way, the table is only scanned *once*. Should be faster.
Window functions are evaluated *after* plain aggregate functions, hence this is possible. Related:

- [Postgres window function and group by exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844903/postgres-window-function-and-group-by-exception/8845062#8845062)

`NULLS LAST` is only needed if the sum can be `NULL` (i. e. `totaldue` can be `NULL`). Details:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

I chose this technique because of your requirement:

> show the 1 (or more, in case of a tie) customer

If you want *exactly* 1 (break ties somehow, if there are more), then `DISTINCT ON` would be preferable:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)