# How to assign groups to another group in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, clickhouse

I have a grouped result/table:

```
tenant|city|count|
1     |A   |36   |
2     |A   |50   |
1     |B   |3    |
1     |C   |6    |
2     |C   |2    |
1     |D   |1    |
2     |D   |2    |
```

Sum of count is 100.

As you can see a city has multiple tenants. If the sum of the count of a city is less than 5% of the total count then that city count should be added to another group named by the 'other' identifier while maintaining the tenant dimension. Resultant data should be.

```
tenant|city    |count|
1     |A       |36   |
2     |A       |50   |
1     |C       |6    |
2     |C       |2    |
1     |other   |4    |  --> Addition of count of B city and count of D city for tenant 1
2     |other   |2    |  --> count of D city for tenant 2
```

I want to produce the same result for two databases PostgreSQL and Clickhouse. Any ideas on how to do this? Even if I will have the query to produce this result in either of the DB, I think it should not be difficult to create the query for other DB too. So answer for either database is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select tenant, grp as city, sum(cnt) as count
from (
  select *,
    case when sum(cnt) over(partition by city) >= 5 
         then city else 'Other' end as grp
  from t
) x
group by grp, tenant
order by grp, tenant
```

Result:

```
 tenant  city   count 
 ------- ------ ----- 
 1       A      36    
 2       A      50    
 1       C      6     
 2       C      2     
 1       Other  4     
 2       Other  2
```

See example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hW2TmBcg7YvLEGYZnNUXP4/0).

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE, this query has to scan the table only *once*:

```sql
WITH tc AS (
   SELECT tenant, city, sum(count)::int AS total
        , sum(sum(count)) OVER (PARTITION BY city) AS city_count
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   )
SELECT tenant, city, total
FROM   tc
WHERE  city_count >= 5

UNION ALL
SELECT tenant, 'other', sum(total)
FROM   tc
WHERE  city_count < 5
GROUP  BY 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1e8347844c891ba9e3ea7dfbe3f37c66)*

Not sure whether ClickHouse supports window functions over aggregate functions like Postgres does. See:

- [Postgres window function and group by exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844903/postgres-window-function-and-group-by-exception/8845062#8845062)

Their [SQL reference](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/) does not address that explicitly. I does say this, though:

> expressions involving window functions, e.g. (count(*) over ()) / 2)
> not supported, wrap in a subquery (feature request)